# "Share" an item to my web service

Tags: data-transfer, share-menu

I am looking for a way to submit content from my Android device via HTTP POST to a web service.

Basically, when I click the Share button on my phone, I would like an option (an icon in the list of share targets) to share that item with my web service.... e.g. https://myserver.com/mywebservice

The web service would handle the data as it needed to (e.g. if the shared item was a URL, or a picture, or... whatever).

Is there some way to do this without having to build an Android app just for this purpose? Maybe there is a customizable sharing app that I have not been able to uncover.

---

**Backstory:** I use an iGrill thermometer & Android app for long barbecue sessions. At the end of the session, the app allows me to export the temperature data over the duration of the session (for graphing etc). I presently share the exported file to my gmail, but then I have to download the file from gmail, and upload it manually to my web server. I'd prefer to go right from the iGrill app to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I found an app that provides this capability (among other useful sharing features. It's called [AutoShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dngames.autoshare&hl=en), and its working great- I had to tweak a line or two in my web service, but now the iGrill data is being shared directly to my web server!